# How to use `docker run --pull always` with locally built containers?

Tags: docker

I would like to use `--pull always` policy with docker run:

```
docker run --pull always url/to/remote/container
```

This works fine until I want to use a locally built image, but with the same command:

```
docker run --pull always local_container
```

Then I get an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for local_container, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

How can I use the same command, while ignoring the `--pull` for locally built containers?Only option I can think of is to push the locally built container to a remote registry before pulling.

Comment: I can also run a local registry server, but I would prefer more straightforward solutions if possible.

Comment: wrap "docker" in a script that does a bit of logic first, such as looking for "local_container" and then just not doing the pull if it's found?

Comment: That means, it would not "always" pull the remote containers.

Comment: sure it would, if you used a consistent naming scheme. A bit of logic in your programming language of choice will solve this. I suggest bash as it's simple to integrate on the command line and is well supported in CI etc.